# mysql combine columns into one and sort in alphabetic order

Tags: mysql

I have a the following table in Mysql:

```
id | Name                  | Abbreviation  |
---+-----------------------+---------------+
 1 | aaaa                  | a             |
 3 | bbbb                  | NULL          |
 2 | cccc                  | c             |
 4 | dddd                  | d             |
 8 | eeee                  | NULL          |
---+-----------------------+---------------+
```

I'd like a query to return the following. If the abbreviation is specified, then return the abbreviation, if no abbreviation, then return name, but abbreviation and name should be ordered alphabetically, so something like this

```
id | Result   |
---+----------+
1  | a        |
3  | bbbb     |
2  | c        |
...
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bumped into solution myself. since `Abbreviation` column can be `NULL` or have value, I can use `COALESCE` that'll get me the first not null column, in other words:

```
select id, coalesce(abbreviation, name) as thename from sometable order by thename;
```